# There is a problem using "since" in Tweety function to extract Covaxin related hashtag tweets from the starting time of Covid'19

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

## It is saying unexpected parameter :since when running the below code

```
import tweepy
# Enter your own credentials obtained
# from your developer account
consumer_key = "wwww"
consumer_secret = "xxxx"
access_key = "yyyy"
access_secret = "zzzz"

# The above keys are mentioned correctly in the programming code

# Twitter authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)   
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret) 
  
# Creating an API object 
api = tweepy.API(auth)

hashtag_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="#Covaxin", tweet_mode='extended').items(5)
    
date_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q="#Covaxin", since="2020-03-31", until="2022-01-09",tweet_mode='extended').items(5)
list = []
for tweet in date_tweets:
    text = tweet._json["full_text"]
    #print(text)
    refined_tweet = {'text' : text,
                   'favorite_count' : tweet.favorite_count,
                    'retweet_count' : tweet.retweet_count,
                    'created_at' : tweet.created_at}
    
    list.append(refined_tweet)
#print(list)    
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('refined_tweets.csv')
```

## It is saying unexpected parameter :since when running the code

I was trying to get the output for all tweets satisfying date query for the particular hashtag Covaxin from the starting of Covid days till now.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual error you are getting.

Comment: I have no full authenticate for archive search. But I can test it recent 7 days search. I got , `tweet id`, `text` and `edit_history_tweet_ids` for #Covaxin. That data is looking for?

Comment: @BenchVue does the Tweepy package only allow for the latest 30 days scraping of data from Twitter? Or can we do it for a longer period,say 2-3 years?

Comment: @PalashPurkayastha, I have no experience  paid account API call but from the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/quick-start/full-archive-search), the default time is 30 days but no limit if set the start_time and  end_time.
I tested last 7 days search with free account.